# NameError var declaration,var scope

Tags: python

I don’t know python and i found this script, I want to use it in blender for a 3d model.There is a name error I don’t know how to solve it,is there any way to make the variable global from the ‘if statement’ ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkoFP.jpg)

I don’t know python i just want to use the script in blender

Comment: please paste the code as text. Don't use images to show the code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure you've done enough research and show what all you tried in your question, "I don’t know python and i found this script" seems to indicate you haven't? Refer: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/)

Answer (score 1):

Just define the `bsdf` variable on the top after the import statement;

```
import bpy

bsdf = None

... rest of the code ...
```